# How to generate Excel and download with OpenAPI?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, swagger, openapi

I have the following endpoint that creates an excel file and adds it to the outputstream. I would like to view the excel and check that it is constructed correctly but I am unable to download it via OpenAPI. OpenAPI downloads a txt file instead of excel and when changing the extension and opening as an excel, i get error about the format of the file.

Java endpoint snippet

```
  @ApiResponses(value = {
          @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", content = @Content(mediaType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"))
  @PostMapping(value = "/download-excel")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  public void getExcelForIds(
          @RequestBody List<Long> ids,
          HttpServletResponse response
  ) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline;filename=\"myfilename.xlsx\"");
    excelWriter.writeIdsToExcel(ids, response.getOutputStream());
  }
```

Response from OpenAPI
[image]

Comment: Does it work if you call the endpoint directly from a browser? The content disposition header looks good, that should be enough for most modern browsers.

Comment: Tip: You can click the "Download" button (in the bottom-right corner of the response text) and save the response to a file. Then you can check if this file opens correctly. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss5i7.png

Answer (score 1):

This is just an issue of bad rendering. The OpenAPI response already indicates that it doesn't recognize the response type. That doesn't mean it's a bad one, just that OpenAPI doesn't support it for rendering. It tries to render it as text but fails there as well. All those question marks in diamonds are bytes that cannot be properly converted to chars - because they aren't chars.

When you copy this badly rendered response to a file and name it to `.xlsx`, your file does not contain the actual response from the server. All those bytes that could not be formatted have been altered.

To properly test this, use a better tool:

- Your browser
- Postman
- curl
- ...